# Prepend String before Moment Timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

I'm using React and Material UI to display `Running check...` when the `clicked` state is `true`. 
Otherwise, I am displaying a timestamp using `react-moment`.

```
 <Typography gutterBottom variant="caption">
   {this.state.clicked 
      ? "Running check..."
      : <Moment local format={dateFormat}>{lastCheckedDateTime}</Moment> }
 </Typography>
```

How would I prefix the timestamp with a string like `Last checked:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what `Moment` component renders but add a span or whatever before it.  Might need to play around with styles if the moment component is a block element:

```js
 <Typography gutterBottom variant="caption">
   {this.state.clicked 
      ? "Running check..."
      : (
        <>
          <span>Last checked: </span>
          <Moment local format={dateFormat}>{lastCheckedDateTime}</Moment>
        </>
      )
    }
 </Typography>
```